# Spatial Join based on dummy variables

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

Here is a simplified version of my problem. I have two shapefiles exposed to different levels of water:

1. Water_0.5m
2. Water_1.0m

All have attribute added to them i.e. Water_0.5m has a column called exposed_0.5 with all values 1, Water_1.0m has an attribute called exposed_1.0 with all values 1. See visual representation where purple represents Water_1.0m and Blue represents 0.5m.

[image: Visual Representation]

I have another shapefile with property data that I want to map these shapefiles to. So basically I want to spatially join my property shapefile with these two shapefiles such that my property shapefile has the exposed_0.5 and exposed_1.0 attributes with values as per their exposure i.e. (null, null), (null, 1), (1, 1).

Here is what I have tried to do. Merge my two shapefiles first to consolidate all data and try to spatially join that to property file. Problem is I am getting values like (1, null) which cannot be possible as anything that's exposed to 0.5m is exposed to higher stuff as well. In fact the only two values I get are (1, null) or (null, 1), so it doesn't take into account the overlap of the two.

How to accomplish this using spatial join?

Comment: First check that "anything that's exposed to 0.5m is exposed to higher stuff as well" is true (in your image it seem that some area are covered by the green (blue ?) polygon but not by the purple). Also you should not "merge" the two polygon layer but use the union tool (or perform two consecutive spatial join on each polygon layer)

Comment: ArcMap or Pro version? Did you see the Join one to Many option in the Spatial Join tool? Also, the period in the field name is asking for trouble though that would affect an attribute join more.

Comment: @J.R yes you are right that's not necessarily true (Although is true 99% of the time) , but the problem that it doesn't take overlaps into account still persists when mapping it to property file. Union did give me what I wanted, but spatially joining that to the property file is still problematic.

Comment: @danak I have the pro version. The problem persists with both types of join.

Comment: Select result by attribute where 1, null. Use field calculator to populate 0.5 field by 1.